# Using logback, but somehow log4j getting initialized

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, logback

Our console application is using logback for logging.
There's a logback.xml file in the classpath.

Logging works as expected (via logback) on most platforms (Linux, Windows, jdk7 or jdk8).

However, on Macs using jdk 6, when running the app we sometimes see:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (our.class.Here).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

It seems for some reason log4j is chosen for logging instead of logback.
In our.class.Here we log through slf4j:

```
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(our.class.Here.class);
```

This is the complete classpath:

```
/path/etc/logback.xml:/path/lib/pdfbox-1.8.4.jar:/path/lib/fontbox-1.8.4.jar:/path/lib/jempbox-1.8.4.jar:/path/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar:/path/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar:/path/lib/bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar:/path/lib/xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar:/path/lib/icepdf-core-5.0.4.jar:/path/lib/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar:/path/lib/jai-core-1.1.3.jar:/path/lib/jewelcli-0.6.jar:/path/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/path/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar:/path/lib/logback-classic-1.1.0.jar:/path/lib/logback-core-1.1.0.jar:/path/lib/itext-2.1.7.jar:/path/lib/hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar:/path/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
```

How could we troubleshoot further to understand why log4j instead of logback is chosen for logging?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you running your app standalone or within a container?

Comment: It's a standalone console application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that log4j.jar was in the user's Java's Extensions directory: `/Library/Java/Extensions`

We found this out by running java with `-verbose`, which pointed out where log4j.jar was loading from.

The workaround was to disable the extensions folder when running our app:
`export JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.ext.dirs=""`

Since the machine was not ours, we could not apply the (better) permanent solution of cleaning up the extension's dir.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `log4j-over-slf4j` in your classpath... perhaps that's what you're missing to ensure any log4j related code goes through the proper slf4j logging impl (logback)?

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: _Our application is using logback for logging_. It seems they **don't** want log4j.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes, I know, that's what `log4j-over-slf4j` does.  Slf4j bridges the API over various logging frameworks (JUL, JCL, Log4j, etc.) into Slf4j, which is configured with a single "binding" (in this case, logback).  You can have multiple bridges (JUL, JCL, Log4j -> Slf4j) and a single binding (the actual logging impl to utilize).  He should also add the missing `jul-to-slf4j` as well

Comment: Reading about it here http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html it seems that `log4j-over-slf4j` should be used as a replacement for `log4j.jar`, which is not in our classpath.
Did I misunderstand?
Later edit: Hmm, but that is a good point though, log4j must be somewhere in the classpath. Perhalps bundled inside one of the library jars. But in this case, would I need to ensure that log4j-over-slf4j.jar is found first?

Comment: @Edi, that is correct.  slf4j "bridges" the APIs used by third party jars you can't control, using things you don't want (log4j, jcl, jul logging primarily).  You do not need to include log4j itself, you instead include the slf4j log4j bridge, which will ensure any code (likely third party) which references log4j classes will be "bridged" through slf4j.  All you need to do is add the "bridge" jars that you want to your classpath